# factoring polynomial by grouping

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I got an excercise which i got stuck, hope some one can help. It's about factoring by grouping.

This is the problem $ab^2 - 2b + 3a - 6$

This is what I tried...
$$ab^2 - 2b + 3a - 6$$

$$(ab^2 - 2b)+(3a - 6)$$

$$b(ab -2) + 3(a-2)$$

I don't know how to continue from here since $(ab-2) ≠ (a-2)$.

In the documentation I have it only says that the answer to this problem is...

$$b^2(a-2) + 3(a-2)$$
$$(a-2)(b^2 + 3)$$

But it doesn't show the steps before this. Assuming my first steps are correct, what doesn't make sense to me is why he changed $b(ab -2)$ to $b^2(a-2)$ they don't produce the same terms

$$b^2(a-2) ≠ b(ab - 2)$$
$$ab^2 - 2b^2≠ ab^2 -2b$$

Comment: I agree with you; $(a-2)(b^2+3)=ab^2-2b^\color{red}2+3a-6$

Answer (score 1):

$$ ab - 2b + 3a - 6   $$
factors just fine

Comment: Isn't it $ab^2$ as leading term?

Comment: @Chief VS I think, Will Jagy wants to say that  there is a typo in the given.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the answer is right? I agree with you.
Because, 
$ab²-2b+3a-6=a(b²-2)+3(a-2)$ or,

$ ab²-2b+3a-6=ab²+2b-4b-4-2+3a=a(b²+3)-2(-b+2b+2+1)=a(b²+3)-2(b-3) $.